# I can't make changes to my model file in odoo9

Tags: odoo

I created new module with model and view, when i add fields in my model file I can't see the changes even if I update/upgrade the module.

there is something weird going on because when I restart/stop /start odoo-server i'm not getting any response.

When I use this command: "./odoo.py -d db --auto-reload" to reload I'm getting an error: odoo.py:error:no such option: --auto-reload

How can I restart odoo server?

Comment: check your __init__.py and __openerp__.py file

Comment: what to check in those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct steps would be (if the module is already installed):

- Update the module and check that the init.py file has the pys imported and the openerp.py file has the views in the data tag.
- Restart odoo server (in ubuntu sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server restart).
- Refresh the module from UI in Configuration > Local modules.